# Doctrine query builder update with join

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have to update some entities (StatistiqueColle) with a condition on a Many-To-Many association field (groupes).

Here is the query I made which doesn't work at the moment :

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->update('PACESStatistiqueBundle:StatistiqueColle', 's')
        ->set('s.banque', 1)
        ->set('s.statsEntrainement', 0)
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('s.groupes', 'g'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('s.banque', ':banque'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('g.id', ':salle'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq($qb->expr()->count('g.id'), ':count'))
        ->setParameters(['salle' => $groupeSalle, 'banque' => 0, 'count' => 1]);
    $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

I saw that Doctrine doesn't accept join with updates. How can I do what I want without a join ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joins are not supported on update and delete queries because it is not supported on all dbms. It won't be implemented in Doctrine 1 or Doctrine 2. You can however get the same affect by using subqueries.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-646

Another solution is to split It into two queries:

- select all records to update
- update records

Like something like this:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$results = $qb->select('PACESStatistiqueBundle:StatistiqueColle', 's')
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('s.groupes', 'g'))
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('s.banque', ':banque'))
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('g.id', ':salle'))
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq($qb->expr()->count('g.id'), ':count'))
    ->setParameters(['salle' => $groupeSalle, 'banque' => 0, 'count' => 1]);
$qb->getQuery()->getResult();

foreach ($results ad $result) {
    $result->setBanque(1);
    $result->setStatsEntrainement(1);
    $this->em->persist($result);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

Comment: I used your solution but I replaced the loop with an update query and a where in condition.
I have a problem left : the first query doesn't work as intended. It's the count condition that doesn't work. When I add this condition, it's not returning any results whereas I checked and I have many results corresponding to a StatistiqueColle only linked to $groupeSalle